# How can I use the HTML5 <button> tag in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, search

I have the following HTML which I'd like to use in my Drupal 6 theme. It needs to replace the search-box code.

```
    <fieldset class="search">
        <input type="text" class="box font-myriad" />
        <button class="btn" title="Submit Search">Search</button>
    </fieldset>
```

I'm trying stuff like

```
$vars['form']['button']['#attributes'] = array('class' => 'btn');
```

in template.php, but no luck so far. Couldn't find much help on drupal.org.

Comment: `<button>` tag is available since HTML 4.0, so the question title should say HTML `<button>` tag. The diff. is big addition of extra attributes in HTML5 spec.

Comment: And `<button>` tag doesn't have attribute 'title' in either HTML 4.0 or HTML 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

drupal doesn't directly support the HTML5 < button > element... since without javascript, it doesn't do much. if you *really* need it, you can use theme_button to override for that particular element.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_button/6

```
<?php
function phptemplate_button($element) {
  // Make sure not to overwrite classes.
  if (isset($element['#attributes']['class'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'] = 'form-' . $element['#button_type'] . ' ' . $element['#attributes']['class'];
  }
  else {
    $element['#attributes']['class'] = 'form-' . $element['#button_type'];
  }

  if ($element['#button_type'] == 'button') {
    // return a fancy html button.
    return '<button ' . (empty($element['#name']) ? '' : 'name="' . $element['#name'] . '" ') . 'id="' . $element['#id'] . '" ' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ">" . check_plain($element['#value']) . "</button>\n";
  } else {
    // retain the normal functionality for anything else
    return '<input type="submit" ' . (empty($element['#name']) ? '' : 'name="' . $element['#name'] . '" ') . 'id="' . $element['#id'] . '" value="' . check_plain($element['#value']) . '" ' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . " />\n";
  }
}
?>
```

then your code to call it would be:

```
$form['content']['search'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#button_type' => 'button',
  '#name' => 'search',
  '#value' => t('Search'),
  '#attributes' => array('class' => 'btn', 'title'=>'Submit Search')
);
```

which should output:

```
<button id="edit-search"  class="form-button btn" title="Submit Search" name="search" >Search</button>
```

tested in Drupal 6.

Comment: again, `<button>` tag is here since HTML 4.0 and Drupal does support this element, the **browser** support of the new HTML5 attributes added to the tag is completely different thing. `<button>` tag does not require the use of JavaScript to provide functionality for a regular form, hence the 'type' attribute submit, reset, button. The important thing to look for, is different implementation in browsers, as IE will send value between the brackets while most other browsers will use the attribute 'value'.